# Создать список из delivery failed ящиков

Tags: exim

Проблема с exim, когда делаю рассылку попадаются ящики с ошибкой доставки, например email не существует или написан не верно. В разультате создается очередь и тормозится доставка. Приходится постоянно очищать список frozen писем, каким образом можно решить такую проблему, например можно ли сделать чтобы автоматически создавался подобный список который я потом обработаю и добавлю эти ящики в блок лист чтобы на них доставка писем не проходила. Или может это костыль и есть какое то более просто решение этой проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, с помощью скрипта *exiqgrep* (идёт в комплекте с *exim*) можно получить список в таком виде (`-b` — это *brief format*, наиболее удобный для обработки):

```
$ sudo exiqgrep -b
1bMyOW-0004uM-RT From: <> To: fluoridesp6@yahoo.com
1bMxBR-0003hp-NO From: <proofreadingtn10@gmail.com> To: smb@something.ru
1bMwlb-0003H8-6Z From: <notepaperevb@gmail.com> To: anna@some.ru;anna2@some.ru
```

я привёл несколько примеров, чтобы было понятнее, как извлекать получателя и разбивать на строки в том случае, если получателей несколько:

```
$ sudo exiqgrep -b | sed 's/.* To: //;s/;/\n/g' | sort -u
```

последняя часть конвейера — `sort -u` — это сортировка и удаление дубликатов.

---

ещё полезной в данном случае опцией скрипта *exiqgrep* может оказаться опция `-o секунды`, позволяющая отображать только те сообщения, что старше указанного количества секунд. например, показ сообщений старше двух дней:

```
$ sudo exiqgrep -b -o $((2*24*60*60))
```

---

подробности см. в документации: [`man exiqgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/exiqgrep).